# LLVM ERROR JIT does not support inline asm

Tags: qt, llvm, root-framework

Just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
got the qt-sdk and when trying to run a simple program using CERN's root
i'm getting :

```
LLVM ERROR: JIT does not support inline asm!
```

i must say that two days ago the computer contained the same OS (since then it has been formated) but everything worked.

What am i missing?

Comment: Which program from CERN was simple? Are you sure that new OS have the same version of LLVM?

Comment: You have not showed your simple program.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of ROOT uses the "legacy" LLVM JIT, which does not support inline assembly. The ROOT developers plan to move in the near future to the newer MCJIT, which does support inline assembly:

http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=15548&p=75022&hilit=mcjit#p75022